# Lock down Linux app's network access

Tags: linux, networking, firewall

I want to run one untrusted application in a Linux VM (host is Windows 10 running VirtualBox). It needs access to another server on my LAN, but I want to block any other network access beyond this one port on one IP.

AppArmor does not seem to allow such fine-grain network restrictions.

I'd rather not block off the entire guest OS's network access, since I want to be able to run e.g. `sudo apt-get update`, but if that's the best I can do, it's acceptable.

What's the best solution? Perhaps a script that sets temporary system-wide firewall rules before launching this program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your VM is Linux I would take advantage of Linux **namespaces** to run that app in a *sandboxed* environment, for example using [Firejail](https://firejail.wordpress.com/). In your case one possible approach would be to create a **virtual network interface** with a limited scope, that can only reach the other server on your LAN.

Then start your app with Firejail, so that it can "see" only one network interface - the restricted one.

From the command line the resulting command would be something along these lines:

```
firejail --net=veth0 yourapp
```

But you could create a custom profile as well.

Comment: Can you clarify how to create that veth0 with access restricted to only one port on one IP?

Comment: To limit traffic to one port, some firewall rules will do. Depends which one is installed on your Linux machine. To actually limit traffic to one specific host that could be done by setting up some routing rules. How to do it depends on what kind of distro you are running, and what firewall, network manager are installed. It's very possible that you can create the 2nd interface in VirtualBox direct.